# Access DOM of a TR in a var

Tags: javascript, dom, element

I'm cloning some table rows and would like to increment the IDs of its child nodes, I've tried doing this by:

```
var rowID = document.getElementById('RowTbl').rows.length / 2;
 var NameRowCopy= document.getElementById('NameRow' + rowID).cloneNode(true);
 NameRowCopy.getElementByID('txtName1').setAttribute('id', 'txtName' + (rowID + 1));
```

So I get the latest set of rows (2 are created each time), and divide by 2 to get the current row ID. I then store the latest table row into a var, ready for cloning, and attempt to set the child node IDs from there.

Unfortunately, Firebug errors out silently so I'm left clueless as to what's going on. What is going on???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such thing as "errors out silently" if you're running in Firebug - it'll either error (verbosely), or do the right thing (silently).

In this case, you don't appear to be adding the cloned node back into the DOM.

Also, `getElementById()` is a `document` method, you can't use it on any arbitrary HTML element.

You *should* be getting an error when you attempt to invoke `element.getElementById()` telling you that there's no such method.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I ended up using child node collections and just traversing through that.